# ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/context/support/LiveBeansView exception is thrown repeatedly in STS

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster, spring-tool-suite, sts

I am working on a jhipster project in STS. When I started the application in STS as a spring boot application I am getting the following exception log.

> 2021-05-30 10:57:14.057 DEBUG 13228 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Exception calling isInstanceOf
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/context/support/LiveBeansView
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.isInstanceOf(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1394)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.isInstanceOf(JmxMBeanServer.java:1091)
> at java.management/javax.management.InstanceOfQueryExp.apply(InstanceOfQueryExp.java:107)
> at java.management/javax.management.OrQueryExp.apply(OrQueryExp.java:97)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.objectNamesFromFilteredNamedObjects(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1496)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNamesImpl(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:560)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNames(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:550)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.queryNames(JmxMBeanServer.java:619)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1485)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.queryNames(RMIConnectionImpl.java:570)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
>
> 2021-05-30 10:57:14.057 DEBUG 13228 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Exception calling isInstanceOf
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/jmx/EndpointMBean
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.isInstanceOf(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1394)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.isInstanceOf(JmxMBeanServer.java:1091)
> at java.management/javax.management.InstanceOfQueryExp.apply(InstanceOfQueryExp.java:107)
> at java.management/javax.management.OrQueryExp.apply(OrQueryExp.java:97)
> at java.management/javax.management.OrQueryExp.apply(OrQueryExp.java:97)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.objectNamesFromFilteredNamedObjects(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1496)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNamesImpl(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:560)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNames(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:550)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.queryNames(JmxMBeanServer.java:619)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1485)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.queryNames(RMIConnectionImpl.java:570)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
>
> 2021-05-30 10:57:14.057 DEBUG 13228 --- [on(3)-127.0.0.1] javax.management.mbeanserver             : Exception calling isInstanceOf
>
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/jmx/DataEndpointMBean
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:427)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.isInstanceOf(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1394)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.isInstanceOf(JmxMBeanServer.java:1091)
> at java.management/javax.management.InstanceOfQueryExp.apply(InstanceOfQueryExp.java:107)
> at java.management/javax.management.OrQueryExp.apply(OrQueryExp.java:97)
> at java.management/javax.management.OrQueryExp.apply(OrQueryExp.java:97)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.objectNamesFromFilteredNamedObjects(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1496)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNamesImpl(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:560)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.queryNames(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:550)
> at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.queryNames(JmxMBeanServer.java:619)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1485)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1307)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1399)
> at java.management.rmi/javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.queryNames(RMIConnectionImpl.java:570)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:359)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
> at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
> at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

But if I start the application in the command prompt there are no exceptions. That makes me wonder if this is an issue in STS. can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add a link to a sample project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are DEBUG log statements and related to JMX so you can safely ignore them in dev by setting log level to WARN or INFO on "javax.management" in logback-spring.xml

```
<logger name="javax.management" level="WARN"/>
```

It's just the MBean server that tries to instantiate some classes to see if it must expose them through JMX, if the class is missing it's not an issue.

Why is it different in STS? I don't know but it could be that STS configures logging differently. Unfortunately for you, STS or plain Eclipse is not widely used in JHipster community.

Comment: this worked fine.. thanks.

"Unfortunately for you, STS or plain Eclipse is not widely used in JHipster community."
then which ide is the suitable one for jhipster?

Comment: The most usual one is IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition or Ultimate Edition.